# How to see a turtle's coordinates

Tags: python

I'm not very good with python, or coding, but my question is:
How can I see where a turtle is?
I want to make it so if you go to a certain place (or around it) some text will display, or something will happen. So either A. how could I just see there location to check if its where they need to be. Or B. see if its at a certain location in another way.

Comment: `turtle.pos()` returns its position

Answer (score 0):

Let me **google** this for you.
Python documentation on turtle is here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/turtle.html

Looks like methods pos(), xcor() and ycor() will return the turtle coordinates.